# Getting "Bad image data." for .webp image extensions when using Batch image annotation offline

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I'm getting "Bad image data." when using the Batch image annotation offline feature for Image Properties Detection on Google Cloud Vision when the image extension is `.webp`.
Now according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files), the `.webp` extension is supported, and indeed when I tried the regular single image synchronous request for the same image it return results normally, so this seems to be an issue with the batch asynchronous feature. Is there a way to get around this?

Sample code:

```py
vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
image = vision.Image()
storage_client = storage.Client("your-GCP-project-here")
base_gs_url = 'path-to-store-image-on-GCS'
url = 'gs://platform-storage-prod/image/f32d82295d744974b15ecfbcba7eb707/73a2d4f550b04fc3a1b097cc3a9b9428.webp' # doesn't work

source = {'image_uri': url}
image = {'source': source}
features = [{'type_': vision.Feature.Type.IMAGE_PROPERTIES}]

requests = [{'image': image, 'features': features}]
output_folder = base_gs_url + uuid.uuid4().hex + '/'
gcs_destination = {'uri': output_folder}

batch_size = 100
output_config = {'gcs_destination': gcs_destination, 'batch_size': batch_size}

operation = vision_client.async_batch_annotate_images(requests=requests, output_config=output_config)

response = operation.result(90)
```

Results will be in the `.json` file created at the specified path.

Comment: Can you share your code and also if it is possible can you share some sample images so that I can replicate in my environment.

Comment: Edited the question with sample code. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I replicated and got the same error message “Bad image data” so  I would recommend you to raise a ticket with[Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub). Or you can also create a thread in Google’s [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).